# How can I create a widget in Odoo 8?

Tags: javascript, widget, odoo, odoo-8

I am beginner in JS.
I have tried to create a simple widget [using this doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/web.html)

**simple.js**

```javascript
openerp.web_sample_widget = function(instance,local) {
    var _t = instance.web._t,
    _lt = instance.web._lt;
    var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;
    console.log("sample widget head"); //It prints fine

    local.WidgetName = instance.Widget.extend({
        start: function() {
            console.log("sample widget"); // this not print
        }
    });

    instance.web.client_actions.add(
      'sample.widget', 'instance.web_sample_widget.WidgetName');
}
```

The first `console.log` is printed fine but the second is not.

**views.xml**

```xml
<openerp>
    <data>
    <template id="assets_backend" name="web_graph assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/web_sample_widget/static/src/js/simple.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is `WidgetName` used somewhere?

Comment: Yes , one of another custom module.
<filed name="field1" widget"WidgetName"/>

Comment: I am not sure if you extended a field widget class. I am not the best with Odoo JS Extensions. Their is a learning curve and I am still not where I want to be. Because you added the widget tag to a field element I think it needs to be an extension of the field class. To odoo just does not know what to do with it and so ignores it. In odoo's interface extension documentation their is some discussion of creating field widgets.

Comment: You may be more interested in the section marked `The Form View Custom Widgets` which would allow you to drop your widget using a widget class. Otherwise look at what they have done with the field widgets.

Comment: Maybe [this example](https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/8.0/addons/hr_timesheet_sheet/static/src/js/timesheet.js) helps you. It is the `weekly_timesheet` widget